# Javascript onclick not firing in IE9

Tags: javascript

Below is my anchor markup which works fine in chrome and firefox but not working in IE9.

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="#" onclick="Javascript:openWidgetWindow(1234);return false;"><img style="border:3px solid white;" src="/media/44540/bookafternoonteagrandhall.jpg" alt="Book table">
<br><br>
</a>
```

and my javascript function is as below

```
<script language ="javascript" type ="text/javascript">

function openWidgetWindow(restaurantId) {
var theme="My Theme";
var left = (screen.width / 2) - (400 / 2);
var top = (screen.height / 2) - (600 / 2);
 window.open("someurlandparameters");
 }
</script>
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: What says the console? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @jantimon: Better yet, remove the entire inline handler and bind it "correctly" :)

Comment: @jantimon: Agreed.  Let's get it working before we go all out :D

Comment: Why are you keeping href attribute there ? `href="#"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="JavaScript:void(0)" onclick="openWidgetWindow(1234);return false;">
 <img style="border:3px solid white;" src="/media/44540/bookafternoonteagrandhall.jpg" alt="Book table">
```